# Probability of detection in a given interval

Tags: probability, integration

I have a half-normal function
$$p(x) = \exp \left( \frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
describing the probability an object at distance $x$ being detected.

[image: the probability curve]

Now I want to simulate a moving object. In a short time period $dt$, the object moves from $x$ to $x+dx$. I think I should integrate the function to get the detection probability in this period, but then I may get probability larger than $1$. Could someone help telling me what is wrong?

Comment: I don't know either a normal function or a half-normal function from a giraffe, so you have to take this response with a **grain of salt**.  If you are assuming that detection occurs in a *microsecond* then, as $x$ goes from point $a$ to point $b$, then I imagine you would want the **average height**, which would correspond to $\frac{1}{b-a} \times \int_a^b p(t)dt.$  The interpretation would be that if $x$ is going to move from $a$ to $b$, some point at **random** in the interval $[a,b]$ will be selected, and detection will be attempted **only once**, and **only** at that random point.

Comment: That is a helpful hit, thank you!